# Can't connect second monitor with HP Pavilion g6 over Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: monitor

I am using HP Pavilion g6 notebook computer with Ubuntu 12.04. I am unable to connect second monitor via HDMI or VGA. I am trying this for few days now and fed up by now. 
I am using Intel graphic drivers which comes as default with Ubuntu 12.04.

Can any one please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably not using the most appropriate graphics driver.

open your terminal and write in the following command:

```
lspci -v | less
```

this will list some of your hardware, including your graphics card, you should have an entry like:

```
00:05.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc Rage XL (rev 27)
```

Next go to your fabricant webpage and search for the appropriate driver for your graphics card and OS.